# Is "substitution" an axiom?

Tags: proof-explanation, relations, axioms

> SUBSTITUTION: Let $\mathbf{F}$ be any algebraic structure. For each $a$, $b\in \mathbf{F}$ if $a=b$ then $a$ can be replaced with $b$ in any mathematical statement involving $a$ and the statement will preserve it's truth value.

In all rigorous mathematical books I have read, the "axiom" of substitution for equality is assumed to be true almost a priori to even listing axioms for equality. Is this because substitution is so fundamental that it is assumed to be understood? Often a book will say that $=$ is an equivalence relation on all numbers so that it is *reflexive*, *symmetric* and *transitive*. This is often treated as the "axioms" for equality. The only issue is the text will often proceed to use some sort of "substitution" rule as well.

For example, in Baby Rudin, the following is the proof for the fact that if $x+y=z+y$ then $x=z$ for each $x$, $y$, $z\in \mathbf{F}.$ $$x=x+0=x+(y+(-y))=(x+y)+(-y)=(z+y)+(-y)=z+(y+(-y))=z+0=z.$$ As I see it, the second, fourth and sixth equal sign above uses an elusive, "substitution like" property that I do not think has been addressed in the book. Why is that?

Also, by my understanding, one only needs "reflexivity" and "substitution" to *prove* that symmetry and transitivity hold.   See [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)) Is it possible to "prove" a substitution property from the three properties of an equivalence relation?

If I were to teach mathematics and give some sort of set of "axioms for equality" could I say that one only needs TWO: first, the reflexive property and second, the substitution property? *Prove* symmetry and transitivity as homework?

Comment: You could, but reflexive, symmetric and transitive relations are called _equivalence relations_ as an important generalization of equality, and substitution is unique to equality, so it may be better to define equality as the unique equivalence relation exhibiting substitution. Or, if you still want to set that homework exercise, you could give it first, present my suggested equality definition, then set another exercise to prove the two equality definitions are equivalent (or prove that fact for your students if you think this second exercise is too hard).

Comment: So you're saying that substitution *can* be proven from an equivalence relation? If not wouldn't it be more precise to say that equality, endowed with the two axioms of reflexivity and substitution "becomes" an equivalence relation as well?

Comment: No, I'm saying equality is the unique equivalence relation exhibiting substitution. This is equivalent to saying equality is reflexive and substitutive, as these imply it's symmetric and transitive. By the way, in first-order logic substitution is actually an [axiom schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema), because you need one such axiom for each unary predicate.

Comment: I am ashamed to say that I haven't heard of this "axiom schema" before. And a quick glance at the link means that I will have to do some work to understand it. Thank you for mentioning it here.

Comment: @J.G. Also my understanding of what your first comment is saying. HWQ1: Suppose that *equality* on $\mathbf{R}$ is, by definition, both reflexive and substitutive. Prove that it is also symmetric and transitive. HWQ2: Suppose that $\diamond$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbf{R}$ that also has substitution. Prove that $\diamond$ is unique and is non-other than the equality defined in "HWQ1."

Comment: Functions are defined in a way so that substitution works. It is a property of functions, or so many other objects we have. It is a natural consequence of defining objects using the equality relation (that's how we define objects basically, we say when they are equal or what they are equal).

Comment: Side note: as often, comparing with computer science is interesting: being less pure, it shows examples where equality is not sufficient to enable substitution. This is called (lack of) referential transparency: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency

Comment: Depending on the treatment , **Substitution** may be **Axiom** or **theorem** & **Identity** may be **Equality** or some even Basic Concept. Check Dirk van Dalen [ "Logic and Structure" ] who "Proves" multiple Substitution theorems & uses 4 Axioms for Identity. Hard to summarize here.

Comment: @Prem Ill check it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Substitution can refer to multiple things. One of which is substituting equal things as you've described here, another is substituting an expression for the value of a variable, which is not fundamentally about equality. I'll mostly talk about the equality-flavored concept.

Substitution can be taken as a rule of inference (not an axiom because it has a premise and a conclusion instead of just being a conclusion), but you can also prove that it is semantically valid.

Let's take a detour into the semantics of [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

In its modern form, $=$ denotes real, bona fide sameness, and it's an inherent part of your logic, not part of the theory of real numbers or whatever theory we're looking at. $2+2 = 4$ isn't expressing a relationship between two distinct objects, it's saying that they *are the same object*. This gets a little more complicated when you think about variables like $x = 7$, but we have to remember that expressions or formulas containing variables always exist in some context and that context is what supplies them with a concrete interpretation. $x = 7$ is not expressing a relationship between some object that is $x$ the variable and the number $7$.

So that's the justification for the substitution rule semantically. Two equal things are really one thing and that's why expressions denoting them can be swapped around.

This isn't the only way of doing things however.

You can treat $=$ as an equivalence relation with some additional rules in your semantics rather than making it "true sameness". Although, again, this is not the modern approach.

Being an equivalence relation is not enough. For the substitution property to hold, $=$ also needs to be a *congruence* with respect to all function and relation symbols, i.e.

$$ x_1 = y_1 \land \cdots x_n = y_n \to f(x_1\cdots x_n) = f(y_1 \cdots y_n) \\ \text{must hold for all function symbols $f$} $$

$$ x_1 = y_1 \land \cdots x_n = y_n \to (R(x_1\cdots x_n) \leftrightarrow R(y_1\cdots y_n)) \\ \text{must hold for all relation symbols $R$} $$

The effect of those rules is two make two things $a$ and $b$ where $a = b$ holds *indistinguishable*. Even if, at a semantic level, $a$ and $b$ are different, no question we can ask using the (first-order) language of real numbers can distinguish them.

We can talk about substitution in deductive systems (i.e. proof calculi), but most of the time that's about instantiating variables rather than swapping around equal things.

I can think of one system that has an equality-flavored rule like this.

Take [equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic).

The substitution rule allows us to infer $P[x := E]$ from $P$. This means inferring $1 = --1$ from $x = --x$. This is *not* fundamentally related to equality.

The Leibniz rule, however, allows us to infer $E[x:=P] = E[x:=Q]$ given $P = Q$. This *is* about equality. This allows us to infer $1 + 3 = 1 + 4$ from $3 = 4$. $1 + 3 = 1 + 4$ is not correct, but the conclusion does follow from the premise.

An version of this rule that's not tied to any specific deductive system is also being used to conclude that $(x + y) - y = (z + y) -y$ in your example from the hypothesis $x + y = z + y$.

Comment: I will have to study this answer quite a bit for me to really understand. But for now, do you think that something is lost, misleading, or incorrect for me to give or treat "substitution" as an axiom? That is, as it is stated in the block quote in my original post?

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson In my opinion, no, but I'm an amateur not a mathematician. Technically substitution of equals is an inference rule, although I suppose you could make it an axiom schema as JG did in the comments. If you're using axiom to mean a basic, fundamental rule that is asserted rather than proven ... then yes it's informative to think of it that way. Your instinct that there's more to equality than just being an equivalence relation is spot on, though.